# Client-side password strength policy verification. CVSS3.1? OWASP WSTG?

Tags: passwords, owasp, cvss

Using the OWASP testing guide, if password strength policy verification is implemented only client-side, can that be considered a vulnerability? In which category?

Also which CVSS it should have?

Comment: It's not a vulnerability of the system, so I'm not sure that it would get a CVSS score.

Comment: You can use OWASP Risk Rating Methodology is a special methodology for Web applications vulnerabilities: https://owasp.org/www-community/OWASP_Risk_Rating_Methodology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be considered as a vulnerability as all the things done only at the client side are not enforced.
This situation is quite equivalent to not have a **mandatory** strength of the passwords.

This topic is described in the OWASP Application Security Verification Standard in the "Authentication" category: https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/master/4.0/en/0x11-V2-Authentication.md#v21-password-security-requirements

This is not a particular flaw (as a CVE with a CVSS score) but a general one (so a CWE).
So you will find details here :

- https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/20.html
- https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/602.html
- https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/521.html

Each article details the above categories of the flaw (in the membership section).

There is no numeric score like CVSS, but you can use the CVSS calculator to estimate it:https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.0.
In your case, a regular user will not try to bypass the password policy at the client side. And if an attacker tries to do it, he can only create a poor secured account for himself.
We can imagine a scenario where the attacker tries to make a victim click a link which change the password for his own account on your website without the client side limitations... but it far simpler to use this link to steal the current password ^^.
So I guess that the CVSS vector is https://www.first.org/cvss/calculator/3.0#CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:N but it is very theoretical.